# Migration from glib-dbus to gdbus

Tags: c, glib

I am trying to migrate my code form `glib-dbus` to `gdbus`. In earlier implementations both the class struct and instance struct could be defined by me and pointers were allowed as properties.

```
struct test {
  GObject parent;
  some_structure *pointer;
};
```

My instance struct had pointers, which I can easily manage.

But in `gdbus`, the code is generated using `gdbus-codegen` - all the class and instance structs are auto-generated according to the introspection XML file.

So I have 2 questions

1. `gdbus` uses Gvariant, which clearly mentions it doesn't supports pointers. Is there any workaround for that?
2. Can I add internal members to the instance struct created by `gdbus-codegen`?

I tried to google these things but as I am new to gobjects and `gdbus` stuff I was not sure.

Answer (score 1):

1) GVariant is used for method parameters, not for instance/app-data pointers
(which are what you're asking about if I understand correctly)

2) For your gdbus-based server implementation, you'd typically use
signal-handlers (as described in
https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.36/gdbus-codegen.html)

Then, to provide provide app-data, you can simply pass that through the
g_signal_connect user-data pointer.

As a alternative, it's possible to use g_object_set_data to attach an app-data
pointer to your instance, which you can then later retrieve with
g_object_get_data.